# Huffman vs. ANS

Tags: huffman-code, image-compression, compression

I have my own JPEG implementation. It had used only Huffman until I discovered ANS which I implemented as well. My test image compressed with these two algorithms yielded the following compression rations:

Huffman: 10.48x

ANS: 10.56x

Indeed ANS proved to be better but only slightly. I am no compression expert but read that ANS was supposed to improve over Huffman like arithmetic coding, what based on this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG should be 5-7%. In my case the improvement is only 1%. Is this something I should expect?

Answer (score 2):

The JPEG standard specifies an arithmetic coder (the QM-coder), but it's often unsupported by implementations. This gives you around 10% better compression over Huffman. With jpegtran, you can transcode between different coding methods.

As to why replacing the default Huffman with a custom ANS back-end didn't help much - could be modeling, could be the size of headers vs. payload, could be something else.

The size of the DCT coefficients for 8-bit input could be up to +-2048 (DC) and these are Huffman coded as 8-bit RRRRSSSS-symbols. Only the magnitude of the coefficient (4-bit SSSS part) gets Huffman coded and the low-order bits are stored without modeling. If only the coder is replaced and nothing else changes, then any improvement is limited to the Huffman coded part.

Also, a more accurate coder requires more accurate probabilities. Transmitting an ANS header is always going to cost more than the equivalent canonically transmitted Huffman code lengths. If there isn't enough data to offset the size of the header, the result may be a net loss.

There's also the opposite problem to 'not enough data'. If the input data is not identically distributed, the probabilities may get muddled together and this gives a hard limit to coding efficiency. QM-coder is adaptive and doesn't have this problem. In this situation, a static coder needs to restart the stream more often.